# Changing body CSS with a jQuery addClass

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am creating a site with a jQuery gallery, and I have the gallery (similar to lightbox) working well.
My question is, can I create a CSS "body class" that I could call from a jQuery event?
This is what I want:
When someone clicks on the image, the gallery appears. Then the body background becomes black, and shrinks to the size of the browser page, and the mainContent disappears only showing the image.
Is there any way to add a body class to the page when a event occurs? Like:

```
 $("div_one").click(function(){
   $("body").addClass("the_new_body_css_look"); 
 });
```

And the CSS:

```
.the_new_body_css_look {

     body { 
       /* the colors */
     }
     mainContent {
       /* the size */
     }
}
```

Comment: `addClass()` is exactly right: http://api.jquery.com/addClass/

Comment: I really doubt "div_one" will select anything unless you have something like <div_one></div_one> on the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the fastest way to check it would be to try it yourself. The answer is yes you can.

Comment: His answer to your question is correct.  Your jQuery code would Add the class to the body class style list.  However your CSS styles are nested incorrectly.

Comment: Then you should ask another question related to your CSS question and accept this answer to this jQuery question.

Comment: so your css should look like this: `.the_new_boddy_css_look { /*body styles */} .the_new_boddy_css_look .main_content { /* styles */ }  .the_new_boddy_css_look .any_other_class { /* styles */ }` if your main content is direct descendant of body you should use `>` operator.